# Python - Read specific lines in a text file based on a condition

Tags: python, file, line, readfile

**Problem Statement:**

I have a file as below.

```
name | date | count
John | 201406 | 1
John | 201410 | 2
Mary | 201409 | 180
Mary | 201410 | 154
Mary | 201411 | 157
Mary | 201412 | 153
Mary | 201501 | 223
Mary | 201502 | 166
Mary | 201503 | 163
Mary | 201504 | 169
Mary | 201505 | 157
Tara | 201505 | 2
```

The file shows count data for three people John, Mary and Tara for a couple of months. I would like to analyze this data and come up with a status tag for each person i.e. active, inactive or new.

A person is active if they have entries for 201505 and other previous months - like Mary

A person is inactive if they do not have entries for 201505 - like John

A person is new if they ONLY have 1 entry for 201505 - like Tara.

Furthermore, if a person is active, I would like to get a median of their **last** 5 counts. For example, for Mary, I would like to get the mean as ((157 + 169 + 163 + 166 + 223 ) / 5).

**Question:**

I would like to understand how I should read this file in Python 2.7 in order to fulfill my requirements. I started with the following but was not sure how I could get previous entries (i.e. previous lines in file) for a particular person.

```
for line in data:
    col = line.split('\t')
    name = col[0]
    date = col[1]
    count = col[2]
```

Comment: Consider using `Pandas`, then you can use the `.groupby('name')` function to look at each person individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd:
df = pd.read_csv('input_csv.csv') # This assumes you have a csv format file
names = {}
for name, subdf in df.groupby('name'):
    if name not in names:
        names[name] = {}
    if (subdf['date']==201505).any():
        if subdf['count'].count()==1:
            names[name]['status'] = 'new'
        else:
            names[name]['status'] = 'active'
            names[name]['last5median'] = subdf['count'].tail().median()
    else:
        names[name]['status'] = 'inactive'


>>>
{'John': {'status': 'inactive'},
 'Mary': {'last5median': 166.0, 'status': 'active'},
 'Tara': {'status': 'new'}}
```

Comment: Does this assume that we have a header row in the txt file? What about the case where there is no header file?

Comment: Yes, this assumes the file has a header row. If there are no headers and you would like to explicitly provide column names, read in the file as follows: `df = pd.read_csv('input_csv.csv', names=['name','date','count'])`

Comment: Thanks. Where are we telling the program to only get the median of last 5 in names[name]['last5median'] = subdf['count'].tail().median() ? What if I want for last 8?

Comment: The `.tail()` part returns the last 5 entries (5 is the default for tail). If you want 8, for eg., you can do `.tail(8)`. You get the point. The median is calculated using, well, the `.median()` part for the last X entries you give it in `.tail(X)`.

Comment: Glad it helped! Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79591/discussion-between-activelearner-and-vk1011).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can solve your problem with dict.

```
import re

spl = """name | date | count
John | 201406 | 1
John | 201410 | 2
Mary | 201409 | 180
Mary | 201410 | 154
Mary | 201411 | 157
Mary | 201412 | 153
Mary | 201501 | 223
Mary | 201502 | 166
Mary | 201503 | 163
Mary | 201504 | 169
Mary | 201505 | 157
Tara | 201505 | 2"""

dicto = {}

listo = re.split("\\||\n",spl)
listo = [x.strip() for x in listo]
for x in range(3,len(listo),3):
    try:
        dicto[listo[x]].append([listo[x+1],listo[x+2]])
    except KeyError:
        dicto[listo[x]]= []
        dicto[listo[x]].append([listo[x+1],listo[x+2]])

print (dicto.get('John'))
```

Output:

```
[['201406', '1'], ['201410', '2']]
```

So, now you have all data, for all users in your dict of dicts and you can do with them what you want

Comment: If my source file is tab delimited text file, how would I read this into the variable spl and how would the re.split function change? Thanks!